Are these called ring binders in American English or files?

This what they look like on the inside:

In many videos, I heard them called lever arch files but the people in those vids were British.

Lever arch refers to a specific mechanism where a lever is used to open the rings. Ring binders don't necessarily have that same mechanism.  I would say ring binder is just a more generic name. I don't really think there is a difference between UK and US usage here. In the UK at least the whole thing could be called a file, or a binder, without specifically mentioning the type of mechanism.  The only thing I would say that is more British (and also more European) is the size. A4 is an ISO paper size which is not as common in the US.

@BillyKerr - you are absolutely right. I used to get secretly annoyed at people who called the things in the picture 'ring binders'. They are not. A ring binder has a number of rings that are split and can be persuaded to open with the fingers, and snapped shut through punched holes, trapping the items to be filed.

@MichaelHarvey I would absolutely still consider these ring binders. The arches are still ‘rings’, even if they’re less circular and stereotypically ring-like than the ones you pry open with your fingers – kind of like how a boxing ring is still a ring, even though it’s square. The only alternative I can think of to call it would be ‘arch binder’, which sounds like an ‘ultimate binder’ (which sounds like a magic spell).

@BillyKerr "In the UK at least the whole thing could be called a file" - I suggest that is a usage difference. I've never heard these called a "file" in the US.

@ToddWilcox - so, not "files" generically when they contain "files"?  The object itself isn't a "file" until you put files in it.

@BillyKerr I’ve never heard one called a “file” regardless of what it contains.

It's a thing that looks and functions like a book binder, with rings that are shaped like arches and clamped with an lever.  Thus, this old native AmE speaker would absolutely call it a "lever arch ring binder".

Yes, they are ring binders and they are files. The first term describes the mechanism that they use for holding paper, and the second term describes the purpose that they have in an office.  Often there is more than one word you could use to name something.
Your files might be ring binders, or paper folders, or box files.
The main use of ring binders is as files to store various documents.
A lever-arch file is a particular type of ring binder in which the ring is opened and closed by moving a lever.
So the picture at the bottom show a ring binder, and in particular a lever arch file, made by the Manor Bindery to look like antique book when closed.

It's one of these strange cultural differences.  In the UK we punch 2 or 4 holes in the A4 sized paper and so binders have two or four rings.  In the US they punch 3 holes in the Letter sized paper, so binders have 3 rings.  So ubiquitous is the use of three holes that "three-ring binder" is the preferred term.

I would use the word "file" for the documents inside the binder, personally, not the binder as a whole.

I'm 50 years old and lived in the US my entire life. I've never once heard a three ring binder called a "file". Also, I've never heard them called "ring binders". It's always been "three ring binder", "binder", or "folder".

@ToddWilcox except OP's picture is of a two-ring, lever arch binder.

@RonJohn Still never heard one called a “ring binder”. I have heard “two ring binder” but they are rare in the states in general so there aren’t many opportunities to called them anything at all. Yesterday I did a search for “ring binder” and at least 90% of my search results said “3 ring binder”. For example, that’s the name of the product category on Amazon.

"Ring binder" is the category.  "Two-ring" and "three-ring" are sub-catregories.  I just Googled "two-ring binder", and the first result was a Lever Arch 2-Ring Binder; US Letter Size.

Since you ask about American English, the style shown in the photo isn't used much in the US. If I were to go to the office supply store, it's likely that the clerk wouldn't know what I was talking about. I'd have to describe the pull hole on the spine, and they'd probably tell me the store doesn't carry that kind of ring binder.
P.S. You could ask if they stock "A4 binders".  Or "D-ring" if the clerk doesn't recognize "A4".
"Leitz A4 Size, 1010 Deluxe 2-Ring Binder, 3" Spine, European Ring Spacing"

The A4 size paper measures 8.27 x 11.69 inches, only slightly larger than the U.S letter size 8.5 x 11 inches.


i second this as USAmerican;   the mechanism fits my expectation of a ring binder, though an uncommon one,  but I've never seen that layout and don't have a name for it.

@MikeM It’s interesting how cultural backgrounds can affect things like these. These binders are so ubiquitous here in Europe that it would never have occurred to me – having never spent any significant amount of time in offices in the US – that they’re not used across the pond.

What does "D-Ring" have to do with "A4"?

You would probably call them binders. I personally would refer to them as 3-ring binders, even though I see they only have two rings inside.
The terminology for binders is closer to books than files. So you might have a shelf of binders (like a bookshelf) rather than a cabinet of binders (like a filing cabinet).

Why would you call it a three-ring binger, when manifestly there are two rings, and the ring connectors look nothing like a three-ring binder?

Do they make 2-hole punches? All the binders I've ever used have been 3-ring binders so that's what I've always called them. I probably shouldn't have added that because it might just be me who does that.

Google is your friend.  I've seen two-hole punches in the Good Ole USA since my teens in the the 1970s.  And if you were my employee, stared at a manifestly two-hole binder and called it a three-hole binder "because that's what I call binders", you'd be unemployed before you too your next breath.  No, I take that back: I'd be too flabbergasted to instantly fire you.  But you would be fired for gross .

@RonJohn LOL, I'm glad I don't work for you!

I guess it's similar to calling something a "red mark" even though it might not be in red.  Any action which manifestly denies in-your-face reality is a fireable offence

@RonJohn Would you fire someone for calling it tinfoil when it's made of aluminum? For calling it a battery when it's a single cell? For calling them french fries when they're not French? Sometimes the common names for things, taken in the narrow literal sense, contradict reality, but that doesn't mean they're wrong--that means that your definitions are too narrow for the domain of discourse in use.

@Hearth honestly, pick better examples.  Tin looks like aluminum (and vice versa).  Single cell whats?  That's right: batteries.  French fries are called French fries not Belgian fries because the people who made those tasty strips of fried potatoes spoke French.  (I'd have no problem calling them Belgian Fries, though.)

@Hearth and if the battery said "double cell" on it, and the equipment required double cell batteries, but you said "single cell" (because that's what you've always said, even though you knew the product needed double cell batteries) which caused the purchaser to buy single cell batteries (because that's what you told them to buy)... and cause the vital equipment not to work, I'd be mighty mighty upset.

@RonJohn And three-ring binders are called that because the prototypical example in most Americans' mind has three rings. See? There are reasons for things to be called that, even when it's not true in the literal sense. // I'll add that no, the proper term--speaking as an electrical engineer--is just "single (electrochemical) cell"; the term "battery" from its inception referred to a bank of many cells (from analogy to an artillery battery being a bank of many cannons). I'll give you the similar appearance between tin and aluminum and the Francophone inventors of french fries, though, fine.

In American English, those are called ring binders. You could simply call them binders too.
Files in American English refers to the stuff you store in the binder, not the binder itself. File also means a sharp object that can be used as a weapon.
If you are using file as a verb instead of a noun, then, it means to send in something.
Never heard the term “lever-arch” used before, but I guess that could be a British synonym. No idea. I am curious to know what they call this in Australia, though some stores have the American term written in the product labels sometimes.

I'm not sure I've ever seen a file that I would describe as sharp, or that would make a very effective weapon. You could probably use one as a weapon, but they aren't sharp enough to easily break skin or anything.

The term is ‘lever-arch’, not ‘level-arch’ – it’s the mechanism whereby you open the metal arch by pulling the lever in the front upwards. (I’ll admit I’d never heard the term before either, but it’s quite self-explanatory.) // @Hearth Nail files are often quite sharp (though also quite small for a weapon, of course), but yeah, files are defined by their gritty/rough surface used to file away at things, not by their sharpness.

+1 but I wonder what part of the US you've heard them called "ring binders". In the mid-Atlantic region, I've only ever heard "three-ring binder", "binder", and "folder"; never "ring binder" without "three". Obviously the one pictured has two rings, which is not common in my experience but I have heard someone say "two ring binder" before.

Binders with both two and three rings exist in the wild, although at least around here (neither Europe nor US) the two-ring variant is more common.  But this is also why "refill pads" (lined writing paper intended to be placed in such binders) usually come with five (or more) pre-punched holes, so that they can fit either type of binder, possibly supporting multiple spacing variations as well.

@Hearth The tang of a file would be a practical stabbing weapon. Not sure if that is what the Megas was driving at though.
